# Unordered-MultiMap of Pairs

Tags: c++, hash, hashmap, unordered-map, unordered-set

I'm struggling to efficiently store information in pairs:

For instance I have two structs that represent (x,y) coords that i wish to calculate and store the distance between.  Currently I am store all the values twice in a

`unordered_map<pair<Struct1*,Struct2*,double>`

My problem is that when searching I want the result `<Struct1*,Struct2*>` to turn up the same value as `<Struct2*,Struct1*>` that way I do not have to store information twice.  I've thought about using a multimap but I think that `std::hash<pair<pointer1,pointer2>>` will hash to the same value as `pair<pointer2,pointer1>` any suggestions on how to do this?

Edit:

I've thought about doing a customer hash that simply adds the two hash values of the pointers using std::hash like:

`size_t operator() (const pair<Location*,Location*> &key)
    {
        hash<Location*> hash1;
        return (hash1(key.first) + hash1(key.second));
    }`

this works when I call find(struct1,struct2), however not when i call find(struct2,struct1)

Answer (score 1):

unordered_map does not only use the hash to identify a key, it also uses a comparison operator :

```
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Hash = std::hash<Key>,
    class KeyEqual = std::equal_to<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator< std::pair<const Key, T> >
> class unordered_map;
```

It is the `KeyEqual` parameter which by default calls `std::equal_to` which by default calls `operator==`.

To do what you want, you can replace the `KeyEqual` parameter whith a custom one that when given a `pair<struct1*, Struct2*>` and a `pair<struct2*, struct 1*>` will return `true` independently of the order.

Comment: I'm getting complier errors my declaration looks like this:
`unordered_map<pair<Location*,Location*>,int,std::hash<pair<Location*,Location*>>,my_hash_pred> dist;`
where my my_hash_pred just returns true if the two pairs are equal, complier errors have to do with std::hash<pair>