# Pair for unordered strings as key for unordered_map

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-map

Possibly related : [ [Unordered-MultiMap of Pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20208498/unordered-multimap-of-pairs), [C++ unordered_map using a custom class type as the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016175/c-unordered-map-using-a-custom-class-type-as-the-key) ]

I would like to use a pair of order-less strings as the key for my unordered_map.

For example I would like key1 to be the same as key2

key1 = {"john", "doe"};
key2 = {"doe", "john"};

Maybe I am missing something really silly here.

Here is my test code (doesn't work as I would want it to):

```
struct Key {
    std::string first;
    std::string second;

    Key(std::string a, std::string b)
    {
        first = a;
        second = b;
    }

    bool operator==(const Key k) const
    {
        return ((first == k.first && second == k.second) ||
                (first == k.second && second == k.first));

    }

};

struct KeyHash {
    std::size_t operator()(const Key& k) const
    {
        return std::hash<std::string>()(k.first) ^
            (std::hash<std::string>()(k.second) << 1);
    }
};

struct KeyEqual {
    bool operator()(const Key& lhs, const Key& rhs) const
    {
        //return (lhs.first == rhs.first && lhs.second == rhs.second);  // not this

        return ((lhs.first == rhs.first && lhs.second == rhs.second) ||
            (lhs.first == rhs.second && lhs.second == rhs.first));

    }
};

void test_unorderedMap()
{
    Key s1("John", "Doe");
    Key s2("Doe", "John");
    Key s3("Mary", "Sue");
    Key s4("Sue", "Mary");

    // first attempt
    std::unordered_map<Key, std::string, KeyHash> m1;
    m1[s1] = "a";
    m1[s2] = "b";
    m1[s3] = "c";
    m1[s4] = "d";

    std::cout << "m6[s1] : " << m1.find(s1)->second << std::endl;   // prints .. a
    std::cout << "m6[s2] : " << m1.find(s2)->second << std::endl;   // prints .. b
    std::cout << "m6[s3] : " << m1.find(s3)->second << std::endl;   // prints .. c
    std::cout << "m6[s4] : " << m1.find(s4)->second << std::endl;   // prints .. d

    // second attempt
    std::unordered_map<Key, std::string, KeyHash, KeyEqual> m2;
    m2[s1] = "a";
    m2[s2] = "b";
    m2[s3] = "c";
    m2[s4] = "d";

    std::cout << "m2[s1] : " << m2.find(s1)->second << std::endl;   // prints .. a
    std::cout << "m2[s2] : " << m2.find(s2)->second << std::endl;   // prints .. b 
    std::cout << "m2[s3] : " << m2.find(s3)->second << std::endl;   // prints .. c
    std::cout << "m2[s4] : " << m2.find(s4)->second << std::endl;   // prints .. d
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For identical objects, a hash must always be equal. So if you consider these to instances equal:

```
Key s1("John", "Doe");
Key s2("Doe", "John");
```

You must also make sure the hash of both is identical. To do that, you could for example first sort both strings and create a hash based on the sorted strings.

Comment: or you could xor in your hashfunction without the shifting. That is probably easier.

Comment: I suspected the same. Thank you very much for helping me confirm my thoughts.